# Free alternative to Sauce Labs

Tags: gratis, web-apps, software-testing

I currently have a free [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/) account which provides access to virtual machines which run many different kinds of operating systems and browsers.
I use this for testing

- web applications
- terminal commands, e.g. testing portability of shell scripts

Sauce Labs have announced that due to an increase in demand, they will be cancelling free accounts.
I only use Sauce Labs occasionally - in the last 6 months I've used it 2-3 times, so I can't justify paying a monthly access fee.

Can anyone recommend a free alternative to Sauce Labs which provides access to different operating systems?